# Unreasonable Editing Practices

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-question

I am annoyed with some editors who edit my questions for no good reason. I consider some people involved in this activity to be dangerously obsessed with it.

In my last question, someone changed 'less expensive' to 'cheaper'. I don't appreciate anyone changing my wording because they think theirs is better. 'Less expensive' is what I want to say and wanted to convey. not 'Cheaper'. My intention was to convey that the alternatives mentioned were expensive TO ME.

So unless there's a misspelling, a grammar mistake, a wrong tag, wrong information or unclear or ambiguous questions, leave my question alone. Otherwise I find this override rude and unnecessary and you are suffering from some kind of an OCD. While SO offers some kind of a WIKI functionality, don't get too zealous with this. A wiki is an informational type of site. SO is for people to get help for their specific issues. The person asking the question know best about the issue and is entitled to have his question. When you are in a meeting, do people talk over you to correct what you are saying or how you say it!? They don't. So why do you think it's OK to do it here? When I ask a question, it's asked for my own good. It's not a work area to exercise your English skills.

I reversed the edit.

Comment: the question in question: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1315010/list

Comment: Please edit the post title. As it'll end up in the URL of the question, stupid URL filtering programs will block the page.

Comment: I agree with Mehrdad. Perhaps changing "anal" to "overly obsessive"?

Comment: Changed the title to reflect a more positive message. I would strongly suggest that this is not reversed. Thank you. Have a nice day.

Comment: Fixed the grammar. You don't "get obsessive," you become it. You get a pony for Christmas if your parents love you. Also, I enjoy irony.

Comment: @Eric: You forgot "get annoyed"

Comment: @balpha: Thanks for that heads up. Zapped it. Pew pew!

Comment: @Shog9 - I am just going to wander pass as if I didn't see anything.... I am waiting for those moderator flags to come through :) I still haven't tried my penalty box powers you know =)

Comment: @Diago Excellent word choice.

Comment: Sometimes, i really wish i could edit [other people's] comments... ;-)

Comment: I have been fighting the urge to turn this question into, "EDITS MAKE HULK ANGRY" for about 10 minutes now.

Comment: Is Welbog in another meeting? I look forward to his response on this.

Comment: @Shog9 - You're right. I better stay quiet. Considering where I come from English is not my first language, however I speak it better then what I write. My spell checker on my MAC hates me already!

Comment: I find it ironic that our man Tony hand-edited when he could have rolled it back and gotten his Cleanup badge.

Comment: Why, Oh Why do I get the feeling this question is going to die a slow and painful death in a very very short time.

Comment: @Eric: I don't know how to rollback. I don't have to rollback to edit and I am not after any badges.
@Diago: After several comments and 7 answers in a few hours, what is your conclusion? Even if it dies, who cares? I just wanted to express an opinion.

Comment: While I can agree the original title was inappropriate so is "a minor edit offended me!" It's incredibly disrespectful to belittle the legitimate concern of people stepping over the line with edits. Yes it was relatively minor but the general issue of respecting people and the content they take the time to write is worthy of a civilized discussion.

Comment: `The person asking the question know best about the issue and is entitled to have his question` I've noticed a pattern in your meta questions, and "entitled" about sums it up. You have no god-given right to _anything_ on the internet.

Answer (score 19):

I agree that this particular edit was out of line, and there is some members of the community that do get a bit over zealous in their edits. However as already mentioned, flag it for moderator **whenever** it occurs and if the user is repeatedly doing unnecessary edits and there is a track record the official site moderators can follow, it will be reversed and acted upon with the user directly.

Comment: That's a great point (and I just got hit by my own 30 second comment throttle)!

Answer (score 13):

But you have to get a chuckle out of the fact that John made a ["grammer" correction](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1315010/list).

Comment: That is funny.  Thanks for pointing out his speling mistake.

Comment: "Grammar" never looks correct to me - I always have to google it to ensure I've not messed up (especially when being pedantic on someone's post).

Comment: This drives me *insane*. I keep on seeing editors writing "spelling and grammer" in review and it has me twitching every time I see it. It makes me want an "Edit approved with comment" feature so I can say "Your edit is ok but *please*, it's 'grammar' not 'grammer'"

Answer (score 6):

From the FAQ:

> Other people can edit my stuff?!
>
> Like Wikipedia, this site is
>   collaboratively edited. If you are not
>   comfortable with the idea of your
>   posts being edited by other trusted
>   users, this may not be the site for
>   you

You are not going to be able to control whether other users, with sufficient reputation, can edit your question so the best solution -- if the edit doesn't change the semantics -- is to simply learn to live with it.  Feel free to roll back edits you don't like, but if you get hung up on "this is my question, it should read the way I want", you're fighting the intent of the site and can only end up frustrated.

Comment: Absolutely people *can* edit your posts; but there is some responsibility that lies with the editor to not make frivolous edits.

Comment: The point is that, like with wikipedia, you can't control it.  If it really bothers you, then maybe, just maybe, this isn't your kind of forum.  And, yes, I agree that editors should be circumspect and generally not make changes that affect the semantics of the question/answer.  One exception (of possibly many) to this rule would be to correct an accepted, incorrect answer.  My general rule is to only edit to improve readability/spelling and comment to point out errors.

Answer (score 5):

> I reversed the edit.

So what's the problem then?

---

To elaborate: the site gives you the tools to correct any bad or useless edits. Even if you don't have the reputation to edit elsewhere on the site, you can always edit or roll back changes to your own posts. That's the privilege of ownership, such as it is on SO.

I took a look at your question, and frankly I don't see what the big deal is - yes, the edit was pointless (a better use of his time would have been to improve the title), but either way it gets the point across. Don't get so upset; editing is as much a part of SO as asking and answering, take it for what it is.

Comment: The problem is that I am not going to monitor my posts to see if they get edited and spend time to reverse. Yes I revered it and that doesn't mean it won't get un-reversed any time.

Comment: 1. You get a notification from that little envelope at the top whenever something happens to your question. 2. Reversed and revered have two very different meanings. Your comment is funnier with the latter.

Comment: Go complain to SO that we can't edit comments for corrections. I don't get notifications when someone edits my questions. I get them when answers are posted.

Comment: **@Tony_Henrich:** if you aren't seeing anything here: http://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/129001?Tab=Revisions then you should report that as a bug - they're supposed to show up.

Comment: There are no little envelope notifications for *answer* edits, as far as I know.

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely agreed that editing from "less expensive" to "cheaper" is trivial and I do not believe should be done. You absolutely can roll the question back to its original state. But be wary of getting into an edit war; if the person seems persistent, flag the post for a moderator to look at and they can lock the post for a time.

Comment: *"less expensive"* and *"cheaper"* may be logically equivalent but they will be perceived differently by any normal person. *"Less expensive"* has a clear implication (at least to me) that the first option is expensive, whereas *"cheaper"* does not

Comment: Also, "less expensive" implies a value proposition, whereas "cheaper" devalues.  This is mentioned all the time in sales training.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with you: In this particular case this was a useless, if not meaning-changing, edit. Unfortunately, that's the nature of a wiki. If a case turns into a problem, call a moderator.

I wonder, though, who exactly you're talking to when yelling "leave the question ALONE"? Meta is not a hangout for evil editors; the person in question appearently doesn't even have an MSO account.

[Yes, Rich B, that means I don't consider you evil. Get over it.]

Answer (score 1):

I fear that, this being a community site, some moderators will disagree with you and change your posts anyway.

You simply should try to not take it personally, since it isn't, they're just thinking that they're improving the quality of your question...

Comment: I understand this particular example was a useless edit, but you'll always have moderators who feel different about these kind of things.

Comment: Talking to yourself, Ivo? That can't be a good sign...

Comment: Except the editor in question wasn't a moderator but another user and the edit could be easily viewed as actually changing the content/meaning of the original question and not providing useful corrections to the question. The ability to edit another presons question is a privilege (hence the 2000 rep required) that should not be used frivously.